# How to set input's default value from another input's value in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 2+
I have a component which accepts two inputs

- `totalCarsNumber`
- `availableCarsNumber`

`totalCarsNumber` is mandatory however `availableCarsNumber` is not

What I'm looking for is how to set the default value for `availableCarsNumber` to be exactly as `totalCarsNumber`

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
@Input() totalCarsNumber: Number;
@Input() availableCarsNumber = this.totalCarsNumber;
```

Comment: I know that I could do this in `ngOnInit` or write the logic for it somewhere but I wanted to know if it's possible using only inputs

Comment: This won't work because when the object is new'd up you will be setting the available cars to what is in the total cars which isn't set yet (not when the total cars value is initialized via an input in Angular)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes, Unless it was especially handled which is what I'm checking

Comment: If these values will every change, you'll want to handle this in the `OnChanges` life cycle hook, not the `OnInit` one

Answer (score 2):

Using property setter in input property we can detect and set default value to it

```
  availableCars:number = null;
  @Input() availableCarsNumber: number = null;

  //This property setter is called anytime the input property changes
  @Input() set totalCarsNumber(val: number){
    if(this.availableCarsNumber === null){
     this.availableCarsNumber = val;
    }
    this.availableCars = val;
  }

  //This getter is called when reading and displaying data
  get totalCarsNumber(){
    return this.availableCars;
  }
```

I made a small demo of it you can check it [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nswzre?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: You need to do a strict `null` check. Your code will behave incorrectly if the available cars number is `0`.

Answer (score -1):

;TDLR Values passed to through Angular's @Input become available after the component is initialised, hence, the value of totalCarsNumber is available in `ngOnInit`. Hence, you have to use `ngOnInit` to implement it.

An optional input needs to be annotated with question suffix. The `number` type should be lowercased. Moreover, we set null as a default value for the optional input so that we can check it later if it has been set.

```
@Input() totalCarsNumber: number;
@Input() availableCarsNumber?: number = null;
```

Then we can use `ngOnInit`to check if the value for `this.availableCarsNumber` has been provided on a component otherwise it will be null and then we set the value to `totalCarsNumber`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.availableCarsNumber = this.availableCarsNumber === null ? this.totalCarsNumber : this.availableCarsNumber;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know if there's a way similar to what I posted above with relying on `ngOnInit ` or any other way
Just by using inputs

Comment: This will be incorrect if there are `0` available cars (it will incorrectly have all cars available). Additionally, if the inputs ever change, this solution will not work.

Comment: Addressed your particular question @MuhammadSaleh.

Comment: I address the issue mentioned by @DanielWStrimpel.

Comment: Your code is still not setting the available cars correctly even with your new changes

Comment: Can we use the safety operator like this in Angular? I didn't know that this is possible! - May I know what does it mean? by default all inputs are optional (as far as I know) and there's no way to mark an optional input or a mandatory one